# How access native provider API with Jclouds 1.7

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, jclouds

Using JClouds, up to version 1.6.x it was possible to access to the native EC2 provider API by using the following idiom:

```
AWSEC2Client ec2Client = AWSEC2Client.class.cast(context.getProviderSpecificContext().getApi());
```

Actually, I copied from the documentation page: http://jclouds.apache.org/guides/aws/

It turns out that in the latest release this method has been removed. Is there an alternative method/way to access to the provider specific features (security groups, key-pairs, etc)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unwrapping the API from the ComputeServiceContext

```
ComputeServiceContext context = ContextBuilder.newBuilder("aws-ec2")
    .credentials("accessKey", "secretAccessKey")
    .buildView(ComputeServiceContext.class);
ComputeService computeService = context.getComputeService();
AWSEC2Api ec2Api = context.unwrapApi(AWSEC2Api.class);
```

Building the API directly

```
AWSEC2Api ec2Api = ContextBuilder.newBuilder("aws-ec2")
    .credentials("accessKey", "secretAccessKey")
    .buildApi(AWSEC2Api.class);
```